# systemd service description in dmesg

Tags: linux, systemd

I have created a basic systemd service file to launch an application. The file is shown below:

```
[Unit]

Description=Starting a Basic Application

[Service]

ExecStart=/usr/bin/app_linux 0x040000

[Install]

WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When I run `systemctl status basic.service`, I am able to see it is running.
I want to see the Description of this service file in dmesg.

Comment: `dmesg` is the kernel ring buffer, intended for messages from the kernel, not from userspace programs. systemd doesn't log there when starting jobs.

Comment: Hi mata, i agree, but how are we getting below messages from systemd into dmesg.            [    4.571277] systemd[1]: Starting udev Kernel Device Manager...
[    4.580546] systemd[1]: Mounted /var/volatile.
[    4.585055] systemd[1]: Starting Load/Save Random Seed...
[    4.594385] systemd[1]: Mounted mount xenstore file system.
[    4.612688] systemd[1]: Started Load/Save Random Seed.
[    4.632603] systemd[1]: Started udev Kernel Device Manager.
[    4.649438] systemd[1]: Started Journal Service.
[    4.677840] systemd-journald[140]: Received request to flush runtime journal from PID

Comment: This question is not actually about programming.  It may attract better answers if asked on the [unix.se] Stack Exchange site instead.

Comment: @anikhan Those messages are from before systemd starts its own journald, which from then on ist used for logging. If you really want systemd log messages to the ring buffer, look at the `ForwardToKMsg` option in `man journald.conf`

Comment: I changed ForwardToKMsg=yes, this is commented previously and i commented ForwardTosys_log=yes, which was previously enabled, even after this i am not able to see in dmesg

Answer (score 0):

Place your service in /etc/systemd/system say you call it basic.service, now enable it by the following command  "systemctl enable basic.service" (this should create a link ln -s '/etc/systemd/system/basic.service' '/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/basic.service'), now power cycle your board, and now check your dmesg output. you can change where the output should be linked to refer [link](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html) for StandardOutput options.

```
[Unit]
Description=Starting a Basic Application

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c /usr/bin/app_linux 0x040000
StandardOutput=inherit

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Thanks For Reply, after this also i am not able to see

Comment: are you able to get messages from other services in dmes output ?

Comment: Yes, [    4.571277] systemd[1]: Starting udev Kernel Device Manager...
[    4.580546] systemd[1]: Mounted /var/volatile.
[    4.585055] systemd[1]: Starting Load/Save Random Seed...
[    4.594385] systemd[1]: Mounted mount xenstore file system.
[    4.612688] systemd[1]: Started Load/Save Random Seed.
[    4.632603] systemd[1]: Started udev Kernel Device Manager.
[    4.649438] systemd[1]: Started Journal Service.
[    4.677840] systemd-journald[140]: Received request to flush runtime journal from PID 1

Comment: Ahh my bad you need to add a line "StandardOutput=inherit"  after ExecStart line

Comment: I tried with this option "StandardOutput=inherit" , i am not able to get the output in dmesg

Comment: replace your ExecStart line to "ExecStart=/bin/bash -c /usr/bin/app_linux 0x040000" also is your app_linux a daemon ? after doing the above change run this following command: "systemctl disable basic.service;systemctl enable basic.service  " (Note: Make sure you make the changes in /etc/systemd/system/basic.service file)

Answer (score -2):

After copying my service file to `/etc/systemd/system/basic.service`:

```
  [Unit]

  Description=Starting a Basic Application
  DefaultDependencies=no

  [Service]

  Type=idle
  ExecStart=/usr/bin/app_linux 0x40000
  ExecStop=/usr/bin/killall app_linux
```

I rebooted and I am able to see message in dmesg